# SMTP GMAIL Server does not respond after connection established (java)

Tags: java, smtp, gmail, response

I try to create my own email client. Before I start creating a GUI etc I try to get the fundamentals working. Sending an email over gmail servers is not working.

I establish a connection to the host *smtp.gmail.com* on port *465* over a *SSL socket*. After I send the EHLO command the server replies with a message. But all other messages are ignored and my reading on the socket times out.

**Why does the server reply to EHLO but then doesn't respond anymore?**

Here is my console output:

```
Successfully connected to smtp.gmail.com:465.
EHLO gmail.com
220 smtp.gmail.com ESMTP p15sm5794363ejx.109 - gsmtp
MAIL FROM:<myEmail@gmail.com>
java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Read timed out
```

And here is the interesting part of my client code:

```
public void connect(String ip, int port, int timeout) {
    try {
        SSLSocketFactory sslSocketFactory = (SSLSocketFactory) SSLSocketFactory.getDefault();
        socket = (SSLSocket) sslSocketFactory.createSocket(ip, port);
        socket.setSoTimeout(timeout);
        out = new PrintWriter(socket.getOutputStream(), true);
        in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()));
        System.out.println("Successfully connected to " + ip + ":" + port + ".");
    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.out.println("Error: Can't connect to " + ip + ":" + port + ".");
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

public String sendMessage(String msg) {
    out.print(msg + "\r\n");
    String resp = "";
    try {
        resp = in.readLine();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return resp;
}
```

In the main function I just read input from the console, send it with sendMessage() and print the responds in a loop. The socket timeout is set to 20 seconds.

Edit: I don't want to use any 3rd party library or *javax.mail*.

Comment: `EHLO gmail.com` - You are telling the Gmail SMTP server ***you*** are `gmail.com`, which it might object to.  I don't know if Gmail cares about this but it might be part of your problem.

Comment: I tried it it with all sorts of paramteres but it always shows the same behaviour.